# How do i update a textfield in javafx in loop ?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have a small javafx application using scene builder which on a button click should read a string from COM port at regular intervals and update in a text field.

But now it only shows the last string if I use a for loop, and nothing if i put the code in infinite loop (That's my temporary requirement).

Can anyone help me so that at each read from COM port the new string is updated in the text field.

[image]

Here is the code I used for both the cases :

Note : In both cases in controller class, I'm getting perfect output on console.

```
public class Main extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the Controller class :

```
// In this case it shows only the last string in the text field.
public class Controller implements Initializable 
{   
    @FXML
    private Button sayHelloButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField helloField;
    @Override

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) 
    {
    }

    @FXML
    public void printHello(ActionEvent event)
    {   
        if(event.getSource() == sayHelloButton)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM22");
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(!serialPort.isOpened())
                    {
                        serialPort.openPort();
                        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
                    }
                    String str = serialPort.readString(10,3000);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    helloField.clear();
                    helloField.setText(str);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    helloField.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method with infinite loop :

```
//this shows nothing in the text field
    @FXML
    public void printHello(ActionEvent event)
    {   
        if(event.getSource() == sayHelloButton)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM22");
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(!serialPort.isOpened())
                    {
                        serialPort.openPort();
                        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
                    }
                    String str = serialPort.readString(10,3000);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    helloField.clear();
                    helloField.setText(str);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    helloField.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How quickly does the application run? If it is executing quickly, you may just never see the updated `TextField` until the last loop ...

Comment: If I got you correct, this is not the case because, yes, the application runs immediately but I've programmed my COM port to send data at intervals of 1.5 seconds and have set the timeout to read as 3 seconds. So I don't think I may miss any update in text field. Also I did sysout of string which in getting printing on eclipse console at regular intervals of 1.5 seconds.

Comment: See my answer below; it is possible that the loop is still blocking updates to the JavaFX Application Thread until the loop is completed, thus only showing the last result.

Comment: Yes, the loop is blocking the updates to the application thread. So I can see last value only of `for` loop. In `while` loop it's not showing even last because it's infinite so last will never come. I'll try the solution and will let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things happening here. In your first example, you state that the console output is correct but the `TextField` only shows the last result.

This is expected if the loop executes quickly. The `TextField` **is** being updated, but it happens so quickly that you can't see it until the loop ends and the last result is still being displayed. Even if you have a delay built into the loop, this could still block the UI from being updated until the loop is completed.

With your **infinite loop**, the issue is that the loop is being run on the ***JavaFX Application Thread*** (JFXAT). This blocks any updates to the GUI until the loop is finished, which is never is.

You will need to move the infinite loop to a new background thread. From there, you can update the GUI using the `Platform.runLater()` method.

```
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM22");
    new Thread(() -> {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                if(!serialPort.isOpened())
                {
                    serialPort.openPort();
                    serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
                }
                String str = serialPort.readString(10,3000);
                System.out.println(str);
                // Update the UI on the JavaFX Application Thread
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    helloField.clear();
                    helloField.setText(str);
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> helloField.setText(e.toString()));
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

This allows your UI to continually update as the background thread sends it new information.

Comment: can you tell me some way to stop this thread when i hit the close button of the window (the top right X buton) ?

Comment: You could change the `while(true)` to check for a different condition instead of `true`. Then just make sure that condition is no longer true when the program terminates.